# how to create event stream using aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My question is not technical but I am looking for architectural input on which tech stack to use. So my use case is: I have subscribers to whom I send a newsletter daily at some time t. I have configured a lambda function to run and send emails. The issue is, currently per second the lambda function sends 3 email, and given the time limit on lambda is 15 minutes, that means I can send roughly 2700 emails. Clearly if the users scale up to 5k or 10k, lambda function will time out.
So I am looking for alternatives to send the email. I am reluctant to use ec2 instance mainly because of cost reasons and want to use lambda function. The other idea i am currently trying is to create another lambda function, which creates an event stream and sends the event to aws sqs queue, which then triggers the lambda function to send the email, but I am highly doubtful this will scale.

Any technical input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to broadcast the same message to all users then you can create an AWS SNS topic.

If you have an email list in S3 or dynamodb then you can create one lambda to read the email ID, then send the email ID to SQS and then create another lambda to send mail.

```
DynamoDB --> Lambda (to read email-ID) --> SQS ---> Lambda (To send email-ID)
```